# JQUERY AJAX ---- Pausing for usability reasons but only when nessesary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a LoadingStatus Function that has two options SHOW or HIDE.

The Show triggers to display when the JQUERY POST is made, the HIDE happens after the RESPONSE comes back.

The issue I'm having is that sometimes this happens so fast that it makes for a bad experience. What I thought about doing was putting in a JavaScript PAUSE, but if the POST takes a while to respond it will take even longer because of the PAUSE.

How can I have my SHOW HIDE function work together, to make sure at minimum the SHOW was displayed to the user for at least 1/2 second?

```
function saveBanner (action) {

    if (action == 'show') {
        // Display the AJAX Status MSG
        $("#ajaxstatus").css("display","block");
        $("#msg").text('Saving...');
    }
    else if (action == 'hide') {
        $("#ajaxstatus").css("display","none");
        $("#msg").text('');
    } 
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var shownTime;
function saveBanner (action) {

    if (action == 'show') {
        // Display the AJAX Status MSG
        $("#ajaxstatus").css("display","block");
        $("#msg").text('Saving...');
        shownTime = new Date().getTime();
    }
    else if (action == 'hide') {
        var hideIt = function() { 
          $("#ajaxstatus").css("display","none");
          $("#msg").text('');
        };
        var timeRemaining = new Date().getTime() - shownTime - 1500;
        if (timeRemaining > 0) {
             setTimeout(hideIt, timeRemaining);
        else {
             hideIt();
        }
    } 
};
```

Comment: I really like the thinking here. But for some reason it keeps going to ELSE {hideIt();} Any ideas why?

Also, I added a } for the last if statement which was missing

Comment: Ok .... changing it
from: shownTime - 1500
to: shownTime + 1500

Did the trick... Does that sound right to you?

Answer (score 3):

In your ajax success callback, you can put the hide command in a setTimeout() for 1500 miliseconds:

```
success: function(results) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    saveBanner("hide");
  }, 1500);
}
```

Of course that would merely add 1.5 seconds onto however long the process itself took. Another solution would be to record the time the process started, with the Date object. Then, when the callback takes place, record that time and find the difference. If it's less than a second and a half, set the timeout for the difference.

```
/* untested */
var start = new Date();
success: function(results) {
  var stop = new Date();
  var difference = stop.getTime() - start.getTime();
  difference = (difference > 1500) ? difference : 1500 ;
  setTimeout(function(){
    saveBanner("hide");
  }, difference);
}
```

You can perform this math either inside your callback, or within the `saveBanner()` function itself, within the `show` portion you would set the starting time, within the `hide()` portion you would check the difference and set the `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Hi jonathan, adding 1.5s to everything is exactly what I'm trying to avoid... Can you help me understand your recommendation so I can set a MINIMUM and not a time tax? thxs

Comment: you can set the minimum as Jonathan recommends by taking the starting time and ending time (when response is returned) and comparing that time to the minimum time wanted. if less, add the time difference, if more, nothing is required.

Answer (score 3):

You can use setTimeout/clearTimeout to only show the status when the response takes longer than a set amount of time to load.

Edit:

Some untested code:

```
var t_id = 0;
function on_request_start()
{
    t_id = setTimeout(show_message, 1000);
}
function on_request_completed()
{
    clearTimeout(t_id);
    hide_message();
}
```

The JQuery handlers should look something like the above. The message will not be shown if you receive a reply in less than a second.

Comment: As Sinu said, you can add a setTimeout to show the saving message only after an amount of time has passed. You use the setTimeout BEFORE calling the AJAX, and call the clearTimeout after the Response came back. If the time alloted to the setTimeout haven't expired yet, the message won't show and your user will be happier. :-))

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.5, you are able to extend the $.ajax functionality by using prefilters.  I wanted a similar experience where a message was shown a minimum amount of time when an ajax call is made.

By using prefilters, I can now add a property to the ajax call named "delayedSuccess" and pass it a time in milliseconds.  The time that is passed in is the minimum amount of time  the ajax call will wait to call the success function.  For instance, if you passed in 3000 (3 seconds) and the actual ajax call took 1.3 seconds, the success function would be delayed 1.7 seconds.  If the original ajax call lasted more than 3 seconds, the success function would be called immediately.

Here is how I achieved that with an ajax prefilter.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
if (originalOptions.delaySuccess && $.isFunction(originalOptions.success)) {
    var start, stop;
    options.beforeSend = function () {
        start = new Date().getTime();
        if ($.isFunction(originalOptions.beforeSend))
            originalOptions.beforeSend();
    };
    options.success = function (response) {
        var that = this, args = arguments;
        stop = new Date().getTime();

        function applySuccess() {
            originalOptions.success.apply(that, args);
        }

        var difference = originalOptions.delaySuccess - (stop - start);
        if (difference > 0)
            setTimeout(applySuccess, difference);
        else
            applySuccess();
    };
}
});
```

I first check to see if the delaySuccess and success options are set.  If they are, I then override the beforeSend callback in order set the start variable to the current time.  I then override the success function to grab the time after the ajax call has finish and subtract the difference from the original delaySuccess time.  Finally, a timeout is set to the computed time which then calls the original success function.

I found this to be a nice way to achieve this effect and it can easily be used multiple times throughout a site.